# WordPress Simplified Chinese language code

Tags: wordpress, localization, chinese-locale

As part of localization for our WordPress website we need to support Chinese simplified script. Not knowing anything about Chinese we did some research and used zh-CN (also known as zh-Hans).

Our client states this is incorrect and we should use: 
ch-cn (also known as ch-hans).  We checked several language plugins and did some research on the internet but this code ch-cn seems pretty rare. Is my client wrong? He wants to use simplified script, chinese PRC

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The client is wrong, and  zh-CN and zh-Hans are correct (their meanings are different in principle, but they boil down to the same language form). In HTML, on the Internet, and in most other contexts that might be imaginable here, a two-letter code as the first part of a language code must be an ISO 639-1 code. The authoritative [registry](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php) assigns  “ch” to the Chamorro language, whereas “zh” is assigned to Chinese.